# Import dynamically classes in Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a structure like this :

```
src
│   main.py 
│
└───modules
    │   __init__.py
    │   module1.py
    │   module2.py
    |   module3.py
```

I want to get all the classes dynamically in the *modules* folder. Therefore, I edited the **init**.py file like this :

```
print(__path__)
for loader, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__):
    module = loader.find_module(name).load_module(name)

    for name, value in inspect.getmembers(module):
        if name.startswith('__'):
            continue

        globals()[name] = value
        __all__.append(name)
```

Is existing a solution to include dynamically all Python classes from *modules* directory in the `__init__.py` file using executable ?

I add all my classes from *modules* folder in the `globals()` to use it in the *main.py* -> it is working pretty well in "python execution".

Now, if I execute the script thanks to Pyinstaller, it is not work because the `__path__` is *bundled_app/dist/main/modules* and the parent folder is not containing the *modules* directory.

I solved this issue adding the module folder as *data_files* in the **spec file**:

```
data_files = [
    ('src/modules', 'modules'),
]
```

But this solution, force me to include all the python files used in *modules*.

Comment: If this is the way your app has to be structured, there really isn't any way around having to include all the python files in your executable

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote won't help pyinstaller in the slightest because it's just doing some static analysis to determine which imports are needed, so very dynamic code like above won't help it find anything.

This is one of the main purposes for PyInstaller [hooks](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/hooks.html), and as the documentation reads:

> Many hooks consist of only one statement, an assignment to `hiddenimports`.

which is exactly what you need to tell PyInstaller there are some imported modules it should include, but that aren't imported through normal `import` statements--and thus that it can't determine on its own.

In fact, each pyinstaller hook is itself Python code that is executed by PyInstaller when building our app's manifest, so you can use something like the code you wrote above to populate `hiddenimports`.

But note that hooks also have available to them some built-in helper functions that might already do what you want, such as [`collect_submodules`](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/hooks.html#PyInstaller.utils.hooks.collect_submodules).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I created a hook file, where I added some Python code : **hiddenimports = collect_submodules('./src/modules')**. Pyinstaller loads this hook file but does not load all modules present in the *src/modules* directory. Do you know what I am missing please ?

Comment: Read the documentation again.  It takes a package name not a filesystem path

Comment: I red it, so I know this. But, I have to import *modules* folder which contains all my custom modules written by me, not Pypi packages (and I don't want to transform these modules into Pypi packages).

Comment: Has nothing to do with pypi.  The term "package" is overloaded.  A "package" at the Python language level is just a module containing submodules i.e. a directory of .py files (typically with an `__init__.py` but since python 3 it's not required).  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=package#packages